# Selecting with dplyr by parameters in column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data table with a lots of columns looking like this:

> sd1_scale1 sd1_scale2 sd1_scale3 ... sd2_scale1 sd2_scale2 ... so on

I manipulate this data with dplyr and use select in this way:

```
  select(code_group, sd1_scale1:sd1_scale13)
```

I want to write function which takes number (sd number) and selects columns by this, something looking like this:

```
 makeData <- function(sdNumber) {

       return select(code_group, sd{sdNumber}_scale1:sd{sdNumber}_scale13)

    }
```

Is it possible to do with dplyr? I've failed to pass into select indexes of columns so I have no idea how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `paste` and `select_`.

Comment: As far as I understood paste works for concatenating string in R, and I didn't find in help select_ function may be you meaning select_vars? And how to pass this expression sd1_scale1:sd1_scale13 to select_vars?

Comment: Make sure your `dplyr` is up-to-date. `select_()` is a version of `select()` that takes strings as arguments. Most every `dplyr` function has a version ending with an underscore that expects strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `select_` as Gregor suggested, but you don't have to.

```
library(dplyr)

x <- read.csv(text = "sd1_scale1,sd1_scale2,sd1_scale3,sd2_scale1,sd2_scale2,sd2_scale3
1,2,3,4", header = TRUE)


makeData1 <- function(x, sdNumber) {
  # Using `one_of` as explained in ?select
  select(x, one_of(paste0("sd", sdNumber, "_scale", 1:2)))
}

makeData2 <- function(x, sdNumber) {
  # Same effect using nonstandard evaluation, see vignette("nse")
  select_(x, .dots = paste0("sd", sdNumber, "_scale", 1:2))
}

x %>% makeData1(2)    
x %>% makeData2(2) # same result
```

I got this from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/djhocking/62c76e63543ba9e94ebe)

Comment: Exellect! Your solution worked even in very complicated case with chaining. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I get an error setting x "Error in scan(file ... line 1 did not have 6 elements"

Comment: @MikeHoney It's difficult to copy/paste tabs.  I've changed them to commas.